# Twitter doesn't accept PHP's cURL, but Linux'

Tags: php, curl, twitter

In attempt to use the [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) API of Twitter I wrote myself some nice PHP script to generate all needed values but if I want to execute this, it just gives me

> string(0) ""

with code 400, which means, according to Twitter's [API Response Codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)

> The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. An accompanying error message will explain further. In API v1.1, requests without authentication are considered invalid and will yield this response.

But this very same request works fine in the normal terminal `curl`.

Here is the snippet from my script, that generates the Linux-Command and executes the request:

```
$auth_str  = "Authentication: OAuth ...";
$headers = array($auth_str);
// ...

if($method == "POST")
{
    echo "curl --request 'POST' '{$url}' --data '{$fields_string}' --header '{$auth_str}' --verbose";
} else
{
    echo "curl --get '{$url}' --data '{$fields_string}' --header '{$auth_str}' --verbose";
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get this particular script to work, but I found [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/), which is a very helpful PHP library that made my life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the `GET/POST` in two different section similar to your commandline example.

```
$ch = curl_init();
if($method == "POST"){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
}
else{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".$fields_string);
}
// remove CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST

// rest of the curl opts go here!
```